# Exibir modal de confirmação após enviar email

Tags: php, formulário, email, bootstrap, modal

Tenho o seguinte código

```
<?php

require_once('PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

PHP_OS == "Linux" ? $quebra_linha = "\n" : $quebra_linha = "\r\n";

//$emp = $_POST["empresa"];
$nome = trim($_POST["nome"]);
$tel = $_POST["telefone"];
$cid = $_POST["cidade"];
//$ass = $_POST["assunto"];
//$msg = $_POST["mensagem"];

switch ($cid) {
    case "ipatinga":
        $destino = "mmarcelovictor@gmail.com";
        break;
    case "fabriciano":
        $destino = "mmarcelovictor@gmail.com";
        break;
    case "timoteo":
        $destino = "mmarcelovictor@gmail.com";
        break;
}


$email = "<br><b>NOME:</b> ".$nome."<br><b>TELEFONE:</b> ".$tel." <br><b>CIDADE:</b> ".$cid."</body></html>";

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsMail();
//$mail->SetFrom('thiagoaug@gmail.com', 'Thiago Londe');
$mail->SetFrom($eml, $nom);
$mail->Subject    = "Agendamento de visita";
$mail->MsgHTML($email);
//$mail->AddAddress($destino, "Thiago Londe");
$mail->AddAddress($destino, utf8_decode('Unimed'));


if (!$mail->send()) {
    $msgerro = "Não foi possível enviar sua mensagem de contato. Tente novamente dentro de alguns instantes.";
} else {
    $msgerro = "Sua mensagem de contato foi enviada com sucesso!";
}

if($mail->send()) { ?>

<script language='javascript'>
    alert('<?php echo $msgerro; ?>');
    window.open('../#agendar-visita','_self');

</script>
```

Gostaria de saber alguma forma de exibir um modal de confirmação de envio assim que o usuário submeter o form.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2):

Ao meu ver, a maneira mais simples de se construir qualquer front-end, incluindo modais, é utilizando [`boostrap`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). Neste caso, você poderia fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

function error($data) {
    foreach($data as $key => $val)
        if(empty($val))
            return "Campo $key vazio, preencha todos os campos para fazer o envio";
    return false;
}

require_once('PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

PHP_OS == "Linux" ? $quebra_linha = "\n" : $quebra_linha = "\r\n";

//$data["empresa"] = $_POST["empresa"];
$data["nome"] = trim($_POST["nome"]);
$data["telefone"] = $_POST["telefone"];
$data["cidade"] = $_POST["cidade"];
//$data["assunto"] = $_POST["assunto"];
//$data["mensagem"] = $_POST["mensagem"];
try {
    $error = error($data);
    if($error)
        throw new Exception($error);

    switch ($cid) {
        case "ipatinga":
            $destino = "mmarcelovictor@gmail.com";
            break;
        case "fabriciano":
            $destino = "mmarcelovictor@gmail.com";
            break;
        case "timoteo":
            $destino = "mmarcelovictor@gmail.com";
            break;
    }



    $email = "<br><b>NOME:</b> ".$nome."<br><b>TELEFONE:</b> ".$tel." <br>        <b>CIDADE:</b> ".$cid."</body></html>";

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsMail();
    //$mail->SetFrom('thiagoaug@gmail.com', 'Thiago Londe');
    $mail->SetFrom($eml, $nom);
    $mail->Subject    = "Agendamento de visita";
    $mail->MsgHTML($email);
    //$mail->AddAddress($destino, "Thiago Londe");
    $mail->AddAddress($destino, utf8_decode('Unimed'));


    if (!$mail->send())
         throw new Exception("Não foi possível enviar sua mensagem de contato. Tente novamente dentro de alguns instantes.");

    $msgerro = "Sua mensagem de contato foi enviada com sucesso!";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $msgerro = $e->getMessage(); 
}

?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-mail" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Envio de email</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p><?=$msgerro?></p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#modal-mail').modal('show');
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado Kenny Rafael.

Mas como posso fazer isso dentro do php? 

Tenho isso: 

if (!$mail->send()) {
    $msgerro = "Não foi possível enviar sua mensagem de contato. Tente novamente dentro de alguns instantes.";
} else {
    $msgerro = "Sua mensagem de contato foi enviada com sucesso!";
}

Gostaria de quando o email for corretamente enviado, invés de exibir uma janela confirmando, exibir o modal de confirmação.

Comment: Vou editar para ficar mais claro!

Comment: Você já está setando a mensagem, independente de erro ou não, neste caso, basta dar o echo dentro do modal como no exemplo, o que alterei na verdade foi só inserir o seu código de envio antes de exibir o conteúdo.

Comment: Consegui Kenny Rafael. Agora me surgiu uma outra dúvida. Meu formulário está validando para verificar se os campos foram todos preenchidos. O meu modal está aparecendo mesmo se os campos não forem preenchidos. Como fazer com que ele apareça somente se todos os campos estiverem preenchidos?

Deixei assim:

$('form button[type="submit"]').on('click', function () {
            $('#modal-mail').modal('show');
        });

Comment: O ideal é que seu modal abra sempre com as informações do que aconteceu, neste caso, dei um upgrade no código, dá uma olhada!